# How can I define this component outside the parent element?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have this component inside another component

```
const selectColumn = useMemo<ColumnDef<Person>[]>(
    () => [
      {
        id: "select",
        header: ({ table }) => (
          <IndeterminateCheckbox
            {...{
              checked: table.getIsAllRowsSelected(),
        ),
        cell: ({ row }) => (
          <div className="px-1">
            <IndeterminateCheckbox
              {...{
                checked: row.getIsSelected(),
                indeterminate: row.getIsSomeSelected(),
                onChange: row.getToggleSelectedHandler(),
              }}
            />
          </div>
        ),
      },
    ],
    []
  );
```

but eslint is giving me this error
[image]

I tried putting the component outside the parent component but I am getting an error because useMemo can't be used at the top level

Comment: If it is outside, you do not need useMemo

Comment: How do I write it without useMemo

Comment: just remove it. const selectColumn = useMemo(() => [...], []) to const selectColumn = [...]

Answer (score 0):

change `const selectColumn = useMemo(() => [...], [])` to `const selectColumn = [...]` and move it outside of the component

Comment: This does not solve the users error. Removing the memoization doesn't change the fact that user is creating components inside a render method.

Comment: This solution is for using selectColumn outside of the component